# c++ design: reducing coupling in a deep class hierarchy

Tags: c++, coupling

Please consider this class hierarchy:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{    
    Base(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4)
    {
        std::cout << "Base::Base:" << arg1 << "," << arg2 << "," << arg3 << "," << arg4 << std::endl;
    }
    void BaseDoWork()
    {
        std::cout << "Base::BaseDoWork" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Derived1:public Base
{
    Derived1(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4):Base(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4){}
    void DerivedDoWork()
    {
        BaseDoWork();
    }
};

struct Derived2:public Derived1
{
    Derived2(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4):Derived1(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4){}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Derived2 myDerived2(1,2,3,4);
    myDerived2.DerivedDoWork();
    return 0;
}
```

The class Derived1 has more coupling than I would like: it has to know how to construct a "Base" class. In a deep hierarchy this would mean propagating the arguments for the "Base" class constructor all the way down the class hierarchy. A change to the "Base" class constructor would require a change to all the derived classes.

My objectives for this class hierarchy are:

1. Derived1 expects a BaseDoWork() method in the base class but does not need to know how to construct the base class.
2. Derived2 knows how to construct a "Base" class.

Ideally I'd like to make Derived1 a template accepting any base class with an accessible "BaseDoWork()" method, along these lines:

```
template <T> struct Derived1:public T
{
    void DerivedDoWork()
    {
        BaseDoWork();
    }
};
```

But if I instantiate the above template as `Derived1<Base>` I can't see how to construct "Base" class without adding knowledge of "Base" constructor arguments to Derived1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is the real hierarchy, if `Derived1` is a `Base` derived class, must know how to contruct a parent class (`Base`).

As I understood, maybe I'm wrong, if `Derived1` is not really a `Base` derived (child) class, and only needs to know it's interface, there is no need to know how to construct a `Base` instance. So you can define Derived1 as follows:

```
struct Derived1
{
    Derived1(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4)
    {}

    .....
};
```

Only `Base` derived classes need to know how to contruct `Base`:

```
struct Derived2 : public Base
{
    Derived2(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) : 
        Base(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
    {}

    .....
};
```

Now, if `Derived2` is really a `Derived1` child, must know how to create it's parent. Previous code became:

```
struct Derived2 : public Base, public Derived1
{
    Derived2(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) : 
        Base(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4),
        Derived1(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
    {}

    .....
};
```

If you must use `Base::BaseDoWork()` method from `Derived1`, you may define classes as follows:

```
struct Base
{    
    Base(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4)
    {
        std::cout << "Base::Base:" << arg1 << "," << arg2 << "," << arg3 << "," << arg4 << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void BaseDoWork()
    {
        std::cout << "Base::BaseDoWork" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Derived1
{
    Derived1(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4)
    {}

    template <typename T>
    void DerivedDoWork(T & base)  // only knows T interface
    {
      base.BaseDoWork();
    }
};

struct Derived2 : public Base, public Derived1
{
    Derived2(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) : 
      Base(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4),
      Derived1(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
    {}

    virtual void DerivedDoWork()
    {
      Derived1::DerivedDoWork<Base>(*(static_cast<Base *>(this)));
    }
};
```

Main keeps the same.

May you need to review this hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the simplest solution. I removed the argument list from Derived1 constructor because decoupling Derived1 from this argument list was one of the main objectives. And the DoWork() methods don't need to be virtual.

Answer (score 1):

When you make `public` inheritance of `Derived1` from `Base`, the result is that `Derived1` already knows how to construct `Base`, so if you want `Derived1` not know how to construct `Base`, maybe it's better to not inherit it from `Base`? Instead, separate `Base` as some kind of performer.

Consider this piece of code, I don't claim that this is solution, but maybe it will push you to other thoughts (the names of classes are the same):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Base::Base:" << std::endl;
    }
    Base(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4)
    {
        std::cout << "Base::Base:" << arg1 << "," << arg2 << "," << arg3 << "," << arg4 << std::endl;
    }
    void DoWork()
    {
        std::cout << "Base::BaseDoWork" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived1
{
    T object;

    Derived1(T obj){ object = obj; }
    void DerivedDoWork()
    {
        object.DoWork();
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived2 : public Derived1<T>
{
    Derived2(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) : Derived1( T(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4))
    { }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Derived2<Base> myDerived2(1,2,3,4);
    myDerived2.DerivedDoWork();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It hasn't occurred to me to store the actual object in Derived1. As far as I can see, the default constructor you added for Base is never called: am I missing the use for this?

Comment: @SimonElliott, default constructor of `Base` is called once when `Derived1` object is created, I just added default constructor to make a `Base` object a member of `Derived1`. You can replace `T object` with `T& object`,`const T& object` or `T* object`, `const T* object` and intialize this reference/pointer in `Derived1` constructor, so `Base` wouldn't be a member of `Derived1`

Comment: That makes sense.I didn't test instantiating a Derived1 on its own.